# Elastic Search AllPermission security manager issue during start

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-security-manager

I am running elastic search with non loop-back IP (production mode) on Windows.
To run ES, I am forking it out (elasticsearch.bat) from a Java app using ProcessBuilder.
However, it is giving me following error:

```
[2018-09-15T00:04:42,617][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [PC-VISHALG] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2018-09-15T00:04:42,632][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [PC-VISHALG] node validation exception
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: granting the all permission effectively disables security
```

It runs fine when I run it as dev mode. I know above issue is raised as part of bootstrap checks, but how to correct/avoid this issue. It has been a blocker for me.
This issue is coming on 6.3.1, 6.3.0 seems to be working fine.

Comment: On debugging more, seems to be issue is coming if I start the ES from a network mounted drive. What can be the reason for it?

Comment: On debugging more, when I start ES directly (not via Java process builder), it starts well if ES installation is on my local drive.
If ES installation is on network drive, it throws out above error. This happens only when ES is running in prod mode. Can anyone please help here?

Comment: Any help here please? This is coming on local system also but it does not occur on every system. Way of starting ES is same but not able to find out why it does not run on some systems.